# Почему генератор PHP замедляет, а не ускоряет программу?

Tags: php

Есть проблема в больших данных. Подумал об использовании генераторов в PHP, чтобы не сохранять данные в памяти, но не получил никакого результата:

```php
function generator() {
    for ($i = 1, $iMax = 5000; $i <= $iMax; ++$i) {
        $next = $i+1;
        yield Yii::$app->db->createCommand("select * from schema.table LIMIT 1 OFFSET $next")->queryOne()['id'];
    }
}

$startMemory = memory_get_usage() / (1024**2);
$startTime = microtime(true);

for ($i = 1, $iMax = 5000; $i <= $iMax; ++$i) {
    $next = $i+1;
    echo Yii::$app->db->createCommand("select * from schema.table LIMIT 1 OFFSET $next")->queryOne()['id'];
}

// Тут используем генератор
foreach ($this->generator() as $value) {
    echo $value;
}

$endMemory = (memory_get_usage() - $startMemory) / (1024**2);
$endTime = microtime(true) - $startTime;
```

Без генератора память изменилась с 2 до 22 мегабайт, а с генератором с 2 до 31 мегабайта. Что я делаю не так?

З.Ы. При тестах код другого метода комментировался.

Comment: А буфер вы очищать не хотите по ходу накопления данных? https://www.php.net/manual/ru/ref.outcontrol.php
echo - накапливает данные, и не отдает их на фронт пока не завершится скрипт или вы явно не скажете ему что делать с буфером вывода, по поводу роста памяти при вызове функций - вполне логичное поведение, вы растите этим стек и создаете кучу "временных" переменных, которые занимают в том числе память, их нужно очищать (unset например, и то не гарантия)

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков я могу заменить `echo` на `$id = ...` и результат тот же

Comment: А в чем тут генератор - ты делаешь и там и там 5000 запросов. Вот если б ты сделал `LIMIT 5000` и в `foreach($row = fetch) { yield $row }`  вот это да.

Comment: зачем говорить что-то про использование памяти, если вы делаете `select *` и из результата берете только `id` ? Не говоря уже о том, чтобы утомить БД кучей запросов, в которых вдобавок не указана сортировка, поэтому в целом результат будет условно "случайным"

Comment: вы лучше напишите какую задачу вы решаете, какой объем данных есть, что вы с ним делаете, и какую проблему в этом видите. Мб вам подскажут как оптимизировать работу с разных сторон, а не какие-то сомнительные тесты.

Comment: пока что - выбирать только нужные поля, создать запрос единожды, параметризовать и подготовить. Выбирать данные пачками нужного размера по 100-500 штук. добавить сортировку, limit-offset переделать в where id > prev limit для использования индекса

Comment: Хочу поинтересоваться, а как вы связали скорость выполнения кода и потребление памяти? На сколько могу утверждать, у них нет прямой корреляции.

Comment: @Borislav отдельные замеры просто.

Comment: @teran выбирал специально все, чтобы больше памяти использовать для тестов. В работе, конечно, делаю только нужную выборку.

Comment: @u_mulder да, надо попробовать выбирать фетчем

Comment: Тогда какая у вас конкретно проблема? Какие показатели, каких нужно добавиться, предоставьте актуальный код, т.к. дискуссия ушла уже в другую сторону и все вангуют.